# How to set xticks for individual axes in seaborn catplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization, catplot

[image]

I have below code with axes in rows but only the last axes shows the xticks while I want to show the xticks on on each Axes. Please someone help me with this and also guide me how to individually control all the elements of axes.

```
g = sns.catplot(data = df_full[df_full['Team'].isin(Test_playing_list)], x = 'Match_Year',  #palette = sns.color_palette('Paired', 7),
                y = 'Win_percent',kind = "bar", height=3, aspect=3, linewidth = 2, row = 'Team', orient="v", facet_kws={'sharey':False, 'sharex':False})
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)


#plt.grid()
plt.show
```

Comment: If you write directly with keywords and not in dictionary form, the x-axis scale will be displayed. `...,orient="v", sharex=False, sharey=False)`

Comment: For the tick label rotations:  `for ax in g.axes.flat:  ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)`